# how to get current page ID in a comment system using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I added a comment system on my blog, the problem is that I can't insert comment on the database, i guess because it can't get the post ID of the current blog. From comments.php, the data will be passed to post_comments.php. how can i pass the post_id on the ajax part (under the script tag)? this is my first time using ajax so i'm not really good with it. Any help will be much appreciated

**comments.php:**

```
<form method='post' action="" onsubmit="return post();">
<textarea id="comment" placeholder="Write Your Comment Here....."></textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Name">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
</form>

<div id="all_comments">
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $databasename="comments";

    $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

    $comm = mysql_query("select name,comment,post_time from comments order by post_time desc");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($comm))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $comment=$row['comment'];
        $time=$row['post_time'];
        ?>
        <div class="comment_div"> 
        <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
        <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p> 
        <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
        </div>
        <?php  
    }   
    ?>
</div>
```

**post_comments.php**

```
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $databasename="comments";

  $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
  $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

  if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name']))
   {
        $comment=$_POST['user_comm'];
        $name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $insert=mysql_query("insert into comments values('','$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
        $select=mysql_query("select name,comment,post_time from comments where name='$name' and comment='$comment' ");

    if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
    {
        $name=$row['name'];
        $comment=$row['comment'];
        $time=$row['post_time'];
       ?>

    <div class="comment_div"> 
      <p class="name">Posted By:<?php echo $name;?></p>
      <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment;?></p> 
      <p class="time"><?php echo $time;?></p>
    </div>
<?php 
    } 
    exit; 
  }  
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `post_id`.So you need to store `post_id` to a hidden field.And check it in `Ajax` call code.

**comments.php**

```
......
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id?>">
<input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
......
```

**post_comments.php**

```
......
if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['post_id']))
   {
        $post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
        // do what ever you wanted to do with post_id 
        $comment=$_POST['user_comm'];

......
```

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly forgot to put name="post_id" in hidden field